# REDHAWK IDE sandbox not appearing in SCA Explorer

Tags: redhawksdr

I am using version 1.9.0 of the REDHAWK IDE on CentOS 6.5 and ran software updates today, made up of OpenJDK updates.

Before the updates, I was able to see the sandbox and chalkboard in the IDE. When I opened the IDE a little while after the updates, the sandbox was gone.

I tried installing Java SE JRE version 1.8.0_05 and restarting REDHAWK IDE without success.

I then tried a fresh IDE installation, which successfully showed the sandbox for two different times starting the IDE. Although, after being closed for an hour or so, the sandbox went missing again.

Does this sound like a java issue? If not, is the IDE breaking itself in some way?

Note that during the time of REDHAWK inactivity I was only using a word processor and a web browser.

Edit: Prior to the updates I had installed the newest GNU HAWK components and was able to load various GNU HAWK components onto the chalkboard with the sandbox still showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and ended up fixing it by commenting out the following line in the eclipse.ini file:

```
#-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, have you found any adverse effects caused by this change?

Comment: Long story short, no I haven't, but I haven't really stress tested it either. Basic development seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

For other people looking at this, I went through the basic example in the Getting Started and the plot window would flash and go away.  It is related to that line in the accepted answer.