# RedHawk IDE cannot connect to domain manager after launch attempt

Tags: redhawksdr, omniorb

I am attempting to test my first waveform built with RedHawk running on CentOS.  It has two components and they run ok in the sandbox, but when I attempt to launch a domain in order to test it as a waveform, it fails with a CORBA_COMM:Failure vmcid SUN minor code 201.  If I turn debug level up to DEBUG or TRACE I can see that the domain manager starts and binds to the Naming Service and the last line in the console is 
Starting ORB!
then a popup giving the CORBA_COMM failure.  I can see the DomainManager proc running with ps and using nameclt I can see the domain registered in the NamingService, but the CORBA Name Service tab in the IDE does NOT show it (both nameclt and the IDE show EventChannelFactory). The IOR returned by nameclt and the one listed in the IDE console DEBUG line differ (shouldn't they match?).

This is somewhat similar to a question asked jerhil Jan 9 although he was using Fedora 20, but there has never been an answer to that question.

Comment: This problem appears to be fixed in v1.10.  I did not need the solutions below for the newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. What seemed to be wrong for me was a fix I used from This stackoverflow article [Sandbox not Appearing in SCA Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143890/redhawk-ide-sandbox-not-appearing-in-sca-explorer/24701592#24701592). If you had this same issue and used this fix I would suggest trying one of these fixes instead as they both worked for me.

1.) (This is probably the better method to try)
Follow the answer given to this question: [Cannot Change Component Property Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335611/cannot-change-component-property-values)

2.)If that didn't work try:

a.)Uncomment the line in eclipse.ini suggested in the linked post
b.)Comment out the line directly below it:
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB

After doing either of these solutions and restarting the IDE I was then able to launch a domain manager from the IDE.

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Sorry, I have been offline for a time, but now that I am back I tried what you suggest and it works for me too.  I still have the Sandbox but CAN now launch a domain successfully.  Thanks.  Still seems like black magic, but we will see if everything else now works.

Comment: Hey Terry I'm glad that worked. I wanted to make sure you saw my edit to the post, as after I answered I found what seemed to be a better solution listed under item 1

Comment: No I missed that.  I will give that a try and see if it is even better.  Thanks for pointing me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the omniNames and omniEvents using this guide: http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainap8.html#x34-430000H

Most of the time hard reset works over soft reset. If that doesn't work, try running the simple waveform mentioned in the redhawk documentation. If you can run that fine, then it's probably the component itself that's causing the issue.