# Cannot launch Redhawk device from IDE

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm having trouble launching a Redhawk device from the Redhawk IDE.  The device is installed in the devices dir at my $SDRROOT (/var/redhawk/sdr/dev/devices/) in the same fashion that the GPP device is.  However, unlike the GPP device, when I select my device and click "Launch a local component" in the IDE, nothing happens -- no dialog, no change in the Eclipse log, etc.

I'm not even really sure how to start debugging this, because there's no indication of a problem except for that nothing happens.  I would expect some logging to occur immediately in the console (my device's constructor includes some debug logging messages).  I've checked that the entry point script is correctly indicated in the spd.xml file, and I can successfully start the device from command line by running the script that I'm giving for that value.

More info about my setup:
Redhawk IDE 1.9 on RHEL 5.5
Note:  I have run into the issue described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143890/redhawk-ide-sandbox-not-appearing-in-sca-explorer) and fixed it in the same way.  I later saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335611/cannot-change-component-property-values) and tried out the solution, since it seemed like the first fix was a bad workaround.  However, modifying the boot classpath isn't helping my issue here, so I've reverted to the original eclipse.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

That does seem odd.  Try the following steps as you debug this issue:

1. Check to make sure there are no hidden consoles using the arrow to the right of the console button
2. Check the error log for any issues: Window -> Show View -> Error log
3. Try launching the device within a Node in a domain and check the console output.
4. Check "ps -ef" to see if the process has started. ps -ef | grep IOR | grep devices Should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry for not following up on this. There were no hidden consoles or errors in the error log. I think that my SDRROOT has gotten into a bad state due to some bad configuration of the oniORB services. I ended up reinstalling Redhawk / omniORB again and making sure things were configured correctly, and the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Since redhawk follows the SCA specifications, in order to launch a device, you must launch it under a node.

So, try creating a new node, include the device, and launch the node under a domain.

Steps:

1. Drag and drop the device project to the Target SDR
2. Create a new SCA Node Project

   Select a domain and create a name for the project. Select next and choose your device.
   Then, hit finish.
3. Drag and drop the node to the Target SDR.
4. Launch the Domain and the node.
5. Expand the domain to find the device name. Right click and choose start.

This should solve your problem. If not, please post further issues.

Comment: See comment above--not sure what the specific problem was, but I believe it was related to misconfiguration of my installation. WRT your answer, must devices always be launched in a node even in debug configuration?

Comment: From my novice perspective, I think devices have to be launched under a node.

Comment: When you select "Launch a local component" on the device it launches it within the IDE sandbox which acts as the node in this case.  Same goes for launching components.  The chalkboard (within the sandbox) acts as the waveform.  You are correct that if you wanted to launch a device into a domain, it would need to be part of a node.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, technically, components are always launched under waveforms and devices are always launched as nodes?